# ViewController present does not always work

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have some problems displaying a viewcontroller in my IOS app.
Sometimes it works and the view is displayed, but sometimes and I guess when the context is a bit different it will not work. No errors or warnings in the  debugger and it can find the ViewController from the Main storyboard (at least it is not nil)
It use to work with self.present but that seems not to work anymore.

```
  @IBAction func showHistoryButton(_ sender: MDCButton) {
        let exercisesHistoryVC = ExercisesHistoryViewController.instantiate(from: .Main)
        exercisesHistoryVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        let appDeligate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDeligate.window?.rootViewController!.present(exercisesHistoryVC,animated: true,completion: nil)
       // parent?.present(exercisesHistoryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: May be it should be `self.present`?

Comment: It won't work if the view controller is already presenting something. I would start with checking the view hierarchy at the moment when the presentation doesn't work.

Comment: This is indeed already the 3e screen in the hierarchy so that might be the problem. Is it possible to present this viewcontroller always on top of everything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code like below,while Present New View Controller

```
@IBAction func showHistoryButton(_ sender: MDCButton) {
        let exercisesHistoryVC = ExercisesHistoryViewController.instantiate(from: .Main)
        exercisesHistoryVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(exercisesHistoryVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
 }

extension UIApplication {
    
    static func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: selected)
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @mistert69,Check and Let me know

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now !  Thanks a lot, I was trying to fix this for more then a day now.

Comment: You need only `if let presented = base?.presentedViewController { return topViewController(base: presented) } return base`.